# По какой причине иногда не работает скролл на сайте?

Tags: google-chrome, прокрутка, firefox, safari

Есть вот такой [сайт](https://o2life.ru/), на котором не всегда срабатывает скролл. Контент прогружается, все скрипты прогружаются также корректно. В консоле ошибок нет.

Самое интересное, что после перезагрузки страницы, начинает работать. Если перейти на какую-нибудь другую страницу, то также рандомно можно получить то же явление.

Очень часто это ловится на мозилле, реже на сафари, на хроме почти никогда.
Я уже с этим неделю почти неделю борюсь, даже не знаю, что вообще может быть. Никаких ошибок или эксепшенов не выводит. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу множественные замечания в консоли по поводу scroll-blocking:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это в браузере chrome.

Нажмите ctrl + F5 на странице чтобы очистить кеш и увидеть их все.

Comment: "ctrl + F5" поправил

Comment: Это очень странно, потому что у меня в консоли такого вообще нет [скрин](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2019/10/04/0005/3941/384869/69/927299bd16.png)
Даже после сброса кэша. Но судя по вашему скрину ругается на jquery

Comment: Попробуйте обновить chrome

Comment: И mozilla и chrome обновлены до последней версии. Такое случается не только у меня, а у большинства людей.

Comment: Консоль должна быть открыта когда вы нажимаете ctrl + F5

Comment: Так и делаю. В любом случаи ваш скришонт дал мне пищу для размышления, спасибо. Буду думать дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Я записал вывод консоли в файл, надеюсь будет понятно. Там вначале идет источник "файл:строка" если он есть, а потом описание проблемы и на новой строке конкретная цепочка связанных функций тоже с источником только на конце:

```
(index):202 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
    (anonymous) @ (index):202

(index):202 [Violation] Parser was blocked due to document.write(<script>)
    (anonymous) @ (index):202

(index):202 [Violation] Parser was blocked due to document.write(<script>)
    (anonymous) @ (index):202

(index):215 [Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.
    (anonymous) @ (index):215

jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
    add @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
    e.event.add @ jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    on @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
    gestures @ owl.carousel.min.js:33
    moveEvents @ owl.carousel.min.js:28
    onStartup @ owl.carousel.min.js:4
    setVars @ owl.carousel.min.js:4
    logIn @ owl.carousel.min.js:3
    loadContent @ owl.carousel.min.js:3
    init @ owl.carousel.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @ owl.carousel.min.js:46
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    f.fn.owlCarousel @ owl.carousel.min.js:45
    (anonymous) @ b6f6767a.js:7
    j @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    fireWith @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    ready @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    J @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2

jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
    add @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
    e.event.add @ jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    on @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
    gestures @ owl.carousel.min.js:33
    moveEvents @ owl.carousel.min.js:28
    onStartup @ owl.carousel.min.js:4
    setVars @ owl.carousel.min.js:4
    logIn @ owl.carousel.min.js:3
    loadContent @ owl.carousel.min.js:3
    init @ owl.carousel.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @ owl.carousel.min.js:46
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    f.fn.owlCarousel @ owl.carousel.min.js:45
    (anonymous) @ b6f6767a.js:8
    j @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    fireWith @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    ready @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    J @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2

jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
    add @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
    e.event.add @ jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    on @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
    gestures @ owl.carousel.min.js:33
    moveEvents @ owl.carousel.min.js:28
    onStartup @ owl.carousel.min.js:4
    setVars @ owl.carousel.min.js:4
    logIn @ owl.carousel.min.js:3
    loadContent @ owl.carousel.min.js:3
    init @ owl.carousel.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @ owl.carousel.min.js:46
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    each @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    f.fn.owlCarousel @ owl.carousel.min.js:45
    (anonymous) @ b6f6767a.js:9
    j @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    fireWith @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    ready @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    J @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2

jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 [Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 311ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took <N>ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took <N>ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took <N>ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took <N>ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took <N>ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took <N>ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 138ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 35ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 30ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 42ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 30ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 33ms

Y4LD69J0lY:1 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
    F @ Y4LD69J0lY:1
    (anonymous) @ Y4LD69J0lY:1
    i.__jivoBundleOnLoad @ Y4LD69J0lY:1
    (anonymous) @ bundle_ru_RU.js?rand=1570100430:1

VM2601:1 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
    value @ VM2601:1
    value @ VM2601:1
    x @ VM2601:1
    S @ VM2601:1
    D @ VM2601:1
    v @ VM2601:1
    a.default.createElement.ref @ VM2601:12
    t.default @ VM2601:12
    (anonymous) @ VM2601:12
    (anonymous) @ VM2601:12

[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 83ms

tag.js:117 [Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took <N>ms

tag.js:1 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 55ms

tag.js:1 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 111ms

VM2513 owl.carousel.min.js:11 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 51ms
```

Comment: Правда у вас мин. файлы и строка не имеет практического значения